# Count missing date sequence in a date range

Tags: date, count, sql-server-2012, sequence

I have the below table with missing dates for each identifier, 
I want to identify how many times the sequence is missed.

Meaning from the below table for identifier 3, date sequence missed three times.
 That is from

1. 12/02/2024 to 12/04/204 --- first time
2. 12/09/2024 to 12/12/204 --- second time
3. 12/19/2024 to 12/22/204 --- Third time

for identifier 4

1. 12/02/2024 to 12/04/204 --- first time
2. 12/09/2024 to 12/12/204 ---second time
3. 12/19/2024 to 12/22/204 --- Third time
4. 12/27/2024 to 12/29/204 --- Fourth time

for identifier 5

1. 12/24/2024 is the missing date

so the output what i am expecting is

```
Identifier  count of missed seq dates

3              3
4              4
5              1
```

Please use the table :

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (IDENTi VARCHAR(50),  StartDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/1/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/5/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/6/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/7/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/8/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/13/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/14/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/15/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/16/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/17/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/18/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/23/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/24/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/25/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/26/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/27/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/28/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/29/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('3', '12/30/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/1/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/5/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/6/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/7/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/8/2024 ')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/13/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/14/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/15/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/16/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/17/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/18/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/23/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/24/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/25/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/26/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('4', '12/30/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('5', '12/23/2024')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('5', '12/25/2024')
```

Comment: I am sorry Lashane, I was not able to think login at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is quick variant:

```
select IDENTi, count(*)
from tt as a
where
datediff(day, (select max(StartDate) from tt as b where a.IDENTi=b.IDENTi and a.StartDate>b.StartDate), a.StartDate)>1
group by IDENTi
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00fda/11

Comment: Wow you are awesome. This is great. But..! i did not read through the code. I should understand the code.